# C# application freezes while using multiple connection string

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2012-express

In my C# WINFORM build in VS2012 and I am using SQLSERVER 2012
I am using 4 connection strings,

```
    public SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DB1;Integrated Security=True;User Id=sa;Password=abc");
    public SqlConnection conatt = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DB2;Integrated Security=True;User Id=sa;Password=abc");
    public static SqlConnection concard = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DB3;Integrated Security=True;User Id=sa;Password=abc");
```

and I am opening and closing connection like this

```
 public void connect()
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        if (conatt.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            conatt.Open();
        }
        if (concard.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            concard.Open();
        }
    }
    public void disconnect()
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        if (concard.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            concard.Close();
        }

    }
```

and whenever I am running, it freezes and after  a minute it gives an error

> Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to to obtaining a connection from the pool.

So I googled and tried to increase pool size but doesnt seem to make much difference.

I am trying to open and close connection on every update and insert query 
for example :

```
public bool UpdateStatusintblOrder(string orderid, bool cancel)
    {
        bool isupdated = false;
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update tblOrder Set Cancel=@cancel Where OrderId=@orderid", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cancel", cancel);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderid", orderid);
            connect();
            if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                isupdated = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Change Order", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); }
        finally { disconnect(); }
        return isupdated;
    }
```

But for select query I return the value to Datatable

for example :

```
public DataTable taxmaster()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string sqlqry = "Select * From TaxTable ";
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlqry, con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); }
        return dt;
    }
```

These all queries are in Class file. which I call in respective forms.

So what am I doing wrong. Because this issue has bothered me for a while and also I need to add one more connection string in same application. Checked my whole codes nothing which could slow the process. However the error, indicates its error related to connection.

So please advise.

Thanks

Comment: If you try to open single connection then does it work or it still gives you timeout error ?

Comment: Earlier had 2 connection it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: ConnectionPool is not much to help because it only works if same connection string everytime. Here you have different connection string for each so it will not help you.

Comment: Right. so thats why there was no difference.

Comment: Run sp_who on the database or check your code to make sure that you always close every connection that you open. And don't open connections that you don't need (eg. don't open 3 at once when you only need 1).

Comment: @fejesjoco it works fine , I had some connections open so closed all of them. And opening one at a time. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the number of allowed Connection is `0` to make unlimited connection.

[image]

but, my opinion is that don't open and close the connection like that. you should use `using` statement to handle connection instead of creating method to disconnect the connection. How you dont need to check state every time.

**For Example**

```
using (SqlConnection cnn1 = getConnection(1))
{
   //...Do whatever want to do
   using (SqlConnection cnn2 = getConnection(2))
   {
       //...Do whatever want to do
       using (SqlConnection cnn3 = getConnection(3))
       {
           //...Do whatever want to do
           cnn3.Close();
       }
       cnn2.Close();
   }
   cnn1.Close();
}


private SqlConnection getConnection(int connID)
{
    switch(connID)
    {
        case 0:
            return new SqlConnection("first conn string");
            break;
        case 1:
            return new SqlConnection("first conn string");
            break;
        case 2:
            return new SqlConnection("first conn string");
            break;
    }

}
```